# How can I render Items from mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I want to render data from MongoDB database into a dropdown menu but it's not working. I am having an error which states "the listName is not defined" but I have declared this in the app.js already. How can I fix this, please?

This is a link to the full code on glitch
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/617e47ff-4d73-45df-ba0f-553d2b9ac034

```
   List.find({}, function(err, foundnames){

   res.render("dropdown", {listName: foundnames});
       });
   });
```

```
<div class="dropdown box2">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    View List
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">

    <%   listName.forEach(function(list){ %>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><%=list.name%></a></li>
    <%  }) %>

  </div>
</div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have there my problems with glitch. i dont get you code anymore, seems as i saved it :/

i modified your code and testet it again. I think there was a problem with sharing variable.

res.render("list", {listTitle: "Today", newListItems: array});

you share the variable newListItems but try to access with listname.
Is that true? i cant have a look at your original code :/

Comment: No. list.name and item.name are different collection in the database. I'm trying to render form the list collection to the dropdowndown menu